Let overlay div become visible through clip-path circle transition / animation
I have two <div>s that fill the entire page. The first div (blue) is shown initially and the second one (yellow) is hidden (display:none). If I click on the blue div, I want to show the yellow overlay div. Then, if I click on the yellow div, I want it to disappear.
That works so far if I simply toggle between display:block and display:none using jQuery. Then I can switch between the two divs.
How could I add a transition effect for the situation when switching from display:none to display:block (and, in the best case, vice versa)?
I'd love an opening/closing circle!
I don't know if this is possible in plain CSS plus JavaScript plus jQuery. If it's possible, I guess it might revolve around clip-path and transition?
If possible, I'd like to avoid a heavy third-party library just for this animation effect.
Please see my sketch:

Thank you very much for your advice!

You need to show us your HTML and relevant CSS, preferably as a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You can’t animate display but you can animate clip-path circle. Have you tried that?

You can animate the clip-path property. You just have to make sure to use circle in both cases (or at least the same for both states). I used 75vmax as the final circle size but this is just eye balling. To be 100% sure that the whole screen is covered you should probably use a calculation for that depending on your screen size or the area you want the circle to cover. You can easily find the math for that online.


let card = document.querySelector('.card');
card.addEventListener('click', e => card.classList.toggle('card--overlay'));
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
.card.card--overlay .overlay {
  clip-path: circle(75vmax at 50% 50%);
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  clip-path: circle(0% at 25% 75%);
  transition: clip-path 1s ease;
}
<div class="card">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>



